# US B1 tourist visa

Tags: b1-b2-visas

My boyfriend will be applying for a tourist visa to come visit me in the US for two weeks. He lives in the UK but he's from Poland so not part of the Visa Waiver program. Is a letter from his employer and 3 pay stubs sufficient? What other information should he take?

On the "address you intend to stay," would it be best to be honest and put my home address or a hotel? Any recommendations would be appreciated. Should he mention he is visiting a girlfriend or say that he’s renting a room? Is it necessary to take a bank statement?

Comment: always be honest of why you are going so he should mention he is visiting you

Comment: `Is it necessary to take a bank statement?` I think you both really need to read up on the documentation requirements for a US visa. Your questions imply you have little knowledge of the process.

Comment: If I knew a lot about the process, I wouldn’t be here in the first place. I have read what is on the website and it is pretty black and white. Which is why I wanted advice and perhaps hear from other that have gone through this process before. It is all very new for me

Comment: You need to do more reading.  You're seeking a visa that does not exist..  There is no such thing as a US "B1 tourist visa".  B1 is a business visa.  The tourist visa is B2.